# vb.net: index number in "for each"

Tags: vb.net, collections

Sometime in VB.net i have something like:

```
For Each El in Collection
   Write(El)
Next
```

But if i need the index number, i have to change it to

```
For I = 0 To Collection.Count() - 1
   Write(I & " = " & Collection(I))
Next
```

Or even (worse)

```
I = 0
For Each El In Collection
   Write(I & " = " & El)
   I += 1
Next
```

Is there another way of getting the index?

Comment: What is worse about the options you listed?  Do you find them to be less clear semantically?  Are you worried about performance?

Comment: just wondering, cause i know VB keeps a hidden index variable. the best option would be to access it. but it seems like there's no way of doing this.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you are using a generic collection (Collection(of T)) then you can use the [IndexOf method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132410.aspx).

```
For Each El in Collection
   Write(Collection.IndexOf(El) & " = " & El)
Next
```

Comment: Wouldnt this be of pretty low performance? It have to seek the whole Collection to get the Index.

Comment: I have no idea what the performance is.  If you are mostly interested in performance, you should update your question to reflect that.

Comment: Sorry if I came off as rude, that wasn't my intention. :)

Comment: Bad assumption that a given element will only occur once within a generic collection.

Answer (score 15):

I believe your original way of doing it with a counter variable is the most efficient way of doing it. Using Linq or IndexOf would kill the performance.

```
Dim i as Integer = 0
For Each obj In myList
    'Do stuff
    i+=1
Next
```

Comment: Agreed.  Wait until VB includes a "For Each object In myList With Index i" construct ;-)

Comment: Or a python like .Enumerate that returns an indexValuePair like a dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

If you need the index then a for loop is the most straightforward option and has great performance. Apart from the alternatives you mentioned, you could use the overloaded [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) method to keep track of the indices and continue using the foreach loop.

```
Dim list = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Reverse() ''# sample list
Dim query = list.Select(Function(item, index) _
                           New With { .Index = index, .Item = item })
For Each obj In query
    Console.WriteLine("Index: {0} -- Item: {1}", obj.Index, obj.Item)
Next
```

However, I would stick to the for loop if the only reason is to iterate over it and know the index. The above doesn't make it clear why you chose to skip the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the index, change the way you iterate through the collection:

You have already come up with the simplest answer:

```
For i = 0 To Collection.Count() - 1
   DoStuffWith(Collection(i))
Next
```